# Route parameter constraint 'int' is not resolved

Tags: resharper, .net-8.0

I have a .NET 7 ASP.NET MVC Web application.  I changed the csproj file to target .net8.0 instead of .net7.0.  The solution builds and runs and I can debug into the code below, but I am also getting a ReSharper warning, **"Route parameter constraint 'int' is not resolved"**.

[image]

I have upgraded Visual Studio to Version 17.8.0 and ReSharper to 2023.2.3.  What is causing this?

Maybe this is not a big problem and JetBrains has just not caught up yet?  *(This is unfortunate since .NET 8 preview has been available since February.)*

Comment: Reboot does not help solve it.

Comment: I am facing the same issue in my all .NET 8 projects.

Answer (score 1):

This issue should be fixed in [ReSharper 2023.3 EAP8](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/nextversion/?section=windows) build. If possible, please try it. Alternatively, you can wait for the 2023.3 release scheduled for December.